# How to swap parameters in shell command

Tags: bash, shell, command

I have a command with parameters in a shell:

```
Command -a -b
```

Assume `a` and `b` are very long directory names, and they are not always the first and last parameters.

However, I need to use this command again. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to go back to the previous command, but this time I need to reverse the order of `a` and `b`:

```
Command -b -a
```

Instead of retyping the parameters again, is there any way to swap them easily?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can use [history substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Designators):

```
$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ !:0 !:2 !:1          # previous command with second arg then first arg
echo bar foo
bar foo
$
```

Comment: If you happen to want to swap the first and last arguments, you can write: `!:0 !$ !^`

Answer (score 18):

You can use <kbd>Alt + t</kbd> to swap the current and the previous word.

[Here](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html) are some more shortcuts.

Mind that you swap words, not parameters. If for instance you have mixed up the order `grep` takes its parameters as in `grep ~/Documents/myFile searchString` and want to correct that to `grep searchString ~/Documents/myFile`, <kbd>Alt + t</kbd>  won't help you.

Go for [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439373/how-to-swap-parameters-in-shell-command/27546557#21439621) instead and do `!:0 !:2 !:1`.

If that's too inconvenient for you to type (it is for me) you can create an alias for that in `~/.bash_alias`:

```
# Swap the first and the second argument of the last command
alias swapArgs='$(history -p !:0 !:2 !:1)'
```

Comment: I like where this is going, but ([see my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561281/is-there-a-shell-which-can-rapidly-allow-reordering-arguments)) I want to go one step further. I want to swap args arbitrarily and without having first executed the command. I can definitely accept requiring zsh to achieve this. Anyone know of a plugin that does it?

Answer (score 8):

## 2022 update

You can easily **cut and paste** arguments, I often cut the last argument and paste it into a different place. `Ctrl-W` will cut the argument before the cursor, and `Ctrl-Y` will paste it.

```
$ # Cursor position is shown as |
$ ls foo bar|

$ # Press <Ctrl-W> to cut the argument just before the cursor
$ ls foo |

$ # Now press <Alt-B> to move the cursor one argument back
$ ls |foo

$ # Now press <Ctrl-Y> to paste the cut argument
$ ls bar|foo

$ # Now press <space> to insert a space between the arguments
$ ls bar |foo

$ # You can safely press <enter> while the cursor is in the middle of the line
$ ls bar |foo
bar foo
```

Comment: I think it's "w" (lower-case) and not "W" (uppercase).

Comment: Beware that Ctrl+w cuts the word until the previous non-alphanumeric character. Fx, doing this on:
```shell
ls bar-foo
```
Will only cut foo, even though the argument is bar-foo.

Comment: @SupAl I just tested in Bash 5.0.17 on Debian, and <Ctrl-W> does in fact cut `bar-foo`. Then pressing <Ctrl-Y> does paste `bar-foo`.

Comment: Interesting. It seems to work on bash but not zsh (I tested it on zsh).